# How does keras handle convolution in case the size of the output is less than the possible number of extracted features using convolution?

Tags: keras, convolution

All is in the question:
Consider the case we specify an output size of 64 but with current convolution layer parameters we can get 128 features.
How is this handled in general and using keras in particular?